# How to add extra values dynamically to h axis in Google Charts?

Tags: google-visualization

Does anyone know how you can add extra values dynamically to the values of the h axis on a google chart? Something like the values in this picture: 
[image]

The dates are added by the google chart, but I want to add the distance on some days. I know that you can do something like this:

```
hAxis: { 
    ticks: [ 
        {v:32, f:"thirty two"}, 
        {v:64, f:"sixty four"}
    ] 
}
```

but how do you this dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into adding an "annotation" column for your domain (x-axis) column.  This would allow you to mark some axis values as needed, though the text from the annotations appears above the axis instead of below.  Example DataTable:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addRows([
    ['Foo', null, 5],
    ['Bar', 'This!', 9],
    ['Cad', 'Also This!', 6],
    ['Fiz', null, 6],
    ['Buz', 'Not This!', 7]
]);
```

see example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/2XsgD/

Comment: Thanks! It's no problem that it's above the axis. I didn't know that you could add annotationtext to the axis, I thought that you could only add it to values in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to populate the chart options (specifically the hAxis.ticks part) as an array (and/or keep the ticks array in a global scope) and redraw the chart every time you want to add a new tick.

Take a look at this small example: http://jsfiddle.net/s2sarunas/9LtPE/

In that example the tick array is global and you populate it on button click by adding specific values and reloading the chart:

```
$('button').live('click', function () {
    global_ticks.push(
        new Date(parseInt($(this).data('year'), 10), parseInt($(this).data('month'), 10))
    );

    drawChart();
});
```